# Google Chrome and proxy server

Tags: c, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I am writing a proxy server and I have a problem. When the proxy is set, Chrome creates some empty connections and no data is being sent to the server. Most likely on them, no data on an entrance are expected. With IE, there is no such problem.

```
IE: 5 connections - 5 HTTP-requests
Chrome: 10 connections - 5 HTTP-requests
```

I ask professionals to answer my question.